# Auto Generate Documentation from Package Metadata

Tags: documentation, tooling

I have a managed package with all of its metadata in a repo. I'm looking for a way to illustrate to non-developer stakeholders what all of the pieces of the package are in a really basic way, like a list of metadata organized by type with the name and description (if available.)

I have a CLI tool that can generate data dictionaries of custom objects and fields and another that can generate docs for Apex classes, but I'm looking for something to generate, for instance, a CSV of all the other metadata types: flows, workflows, page layouts, etc.